# Can you autofill WorksheetFunction formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know if it is possible to apply the WorksheetFunction on a range instantly. 
For example, say I want to Vlookup with the Index 1 & 3 to get their ID Num 
|Index|Name|Sales|ID Num|
|-|-|-|-|-|
|1| A| 2| 123|
|2| B| 3| 321|
|3| A| 5| 456|
|4| A| 1| 654|

I managed to achive it on the vlookup function:

```
Range("J2:J3")=WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("I2:I3"), Range("A:D"), 4, 0)
```

Where :

- "I2:I3" are the cells storing the criteria 1 & 3
- "A:D" is the column Index, Name, Sales & ID Num

The excel formula version is `"=VLOOKUP(I2,A:D,4,0)"`

It returned me :

- cell "J2" = 123
- cell "J3" = 456

,which is good but when I use the same methodology on the `SUMIF` function, it gives me a **run-time error Type mismatch** 
Here is the code : `Range("G2:G3") = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("B:B"), Range("F2:F3"), Range("C:C"))`

Where :

- "B:B" is the column Name
- "F2:F3" are the cells storing A & B
- "C:C" is the column Sales

The excel formula version is `"=SUMIF(B:B;F2;C:C)"`

In the formula above, I want to get the total sales for A & B

Have I done something wrong?Or is there an alternative?

Please let me know

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the late-bound version: `Application.SumIf`.